# Plugin for Visual Studio to visualize code complexity over each method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

I know NDepend which is a pretty complete tool for calculating code metrics but its not graphically integrated in Visual Studio source code editor.

I'd like to see, at first glance, if the method I'm currently watching in the Source Code Editor "should" be refactored (visualizing the code complexity in a small progress bar would be a good beginning).

Comment: Actually we have plans to integrate our issues in source code editor for 2018 Q1. Please come back to us at support at ndepend dot com to enroll in private betas.